# How do I embed an exe file in an MS Access Form and Run it at run time?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm using MS Access 2003 for Special and old problems with the .mdb project

I want to embed my files like .txt or .exe or .pdf and run them at runtime or write that on disk.

What have I tried :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFCzL.png)

I don't know what's the code to do what I need I couldn't find my solution on internet.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

'Me.OLEUnbound2.Application.Run  

      Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = Me.OLEBound1.Object
    'obj.DoVerb (acPrimaryVerb)
  
End Sub
```

Update:
I wrote a C# program called BMH.exe, which I open and run through Access, but I want this file to be in my source in any way possible so that the user does not have to place this file next to the program or somewhere It has Windows,

I also don't want to do things like downloading from the site, creating an installation file, I just want to access this program in any possible way through the embedded file itself, which is in the form of OLE Object and from the Packager Shell class. Write the object to a specific address or run it directly from Access itself

Comment: You couldn't find any solutions on the internet, because what you're trying to do is extremely dangerous. Please explain in a few words your overall goal, I'm certain there are better ways to do it.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like a trojan (retrieving an exe from a database then running it), so is a good way to get trouble with antivirus software. You essentially have 3  steps: write a file from disk to the database, read it from the database to disk, run it, all of which are duplicates here. I strongly recommend against using the GUI and OLE Packager Shell objects, since those can contain multiple files and make everything substantially harder.

Comment: *...or somewhere It has Windows.* You mean the Windows operating system? How's the C# program supposed to run?

Comment: You can save the program in a shared folder and run from VBA via the `Shell()` function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009023)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Answer (score -1):

You can save the file as attachment in attachement field. If it will not accept an .exe file switch the extension and switch it back when exporting, you can do all this with code. Alternatively you can store the file as binary in an Ole field.